# Fetch more and append records using Data Repeater and pagination Site.com

Tags: javascript, site.com, data, feeditem, pagination

I want to fetch more records and display the previous records along with newly fetched records using pagination. But the default behavior of pagination is to override previous with new one.

Is there any way that I can append the newly fetched records with previous records?

One solution I can think of is store the current records and append with newly records when the page loads is complete for the next request. Just looking for better solution.

Any help will be appreciated.